# DSolve::deqx: Supplied equations are not differential or integral equations of the given functions

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following set of ODEs for u(x) but I am stuck with this error. I am not sure why this is happening. Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thank you :)
(code is in the comments)

[image: screenshot of mathemtica code and error]

'''
Here is the code if that helps:

```
    '''
    ClearAll["Global'*"];


    (Subscript[\[Beta], 
         0]^2)*(\[Gamma]^2)*(\[Sigma]^2) - (Subscript[\[Beta], 
         0]^2)*(\[Sigma]^2) + 2*(\[Gamma]^2)*\[Lambda] + 
      2*(\[Gamma]^2)*Subscript[\[Mu], \[Infinity]] - 
      2*(\[Gamma]^2)*Subscript[\[Mu], 0] + 
      2*\[Gamma]*Subscript[\[Mu], 0] - 2*\[Lambda] - 
      2*Subscript[\[Mu], \[Infinity]] + 4 Subscript[\[Mu], 0] - 
      4*\[Gamma]*Subscript[\[Mu], 0]*Subscript[q, 2] > 0

    a[i_, x_] := 
     Piecewise[{{-\[Lambda]*\[Gamma]^2 + 
         x*(Subscript[\[Mu], 
             0]*(x*(2*\[Gamma]*Subscript[q, 2] - \[Gamma] + 
                  1) + \[Gamma]^2 - 1) + 
            Subscript[\[Mu], \[Infinity]]*(x*(\[Gamma] - 
                  2*\[Gamma]*Subscript[p, 2]) + 
               2*\[Gamma]*Subscript[p, 2] - \[Gamma]^2 - \[Gamma])), 
        i == 0},
       {x*(\[Lambda] - 
            2*\[Lambda]*x) + (x^2)*(Subscript[\[Mu], 0]*(3*x - 3) + 
            Subscript[\[Mu], \[Infinity]]*(2 - 3*x) - 
            0.5*(\[Sigma]^2)*(Subscript[\[Beta], 0]^2)*(\[Gamma]^2 - 
               12*x^2 + 15*x - 4)), i == 1},
       {(x^2)*\[Lambda] - (x^3)*(Subscript[\[Mu], 0] - 
            Subscript[\[Mu], \[Infinity]] + (8*x - 
               5)*0.5*(\[Sigma]^2)*(Subscript[\[Beta], 0]^2)), i == 2}, 
       {0.5*(\[Sigma]^2)*(Subscript[\[Beta], 0]^2)*(x^4), i == 3}}]
    
    b[x_, k_] := (1/(k!))*\!\(
    \*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = k\), \(3\)]\((\((\(i!\))\)*
         a[i, x])\)\)


    sol = DSolve[{ \!\(
    \*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(k = 
           0\), \(3\)]\((\((\((1 \[Minus] x)\)^\((\ k + 1)\))\)\ *b[x, k]*
           D[u[x], \ {x, \ k}])\)\) == 
        c*((\[Gamma]^2) \[Minus] 1)* x*(1 \[Minus] x),
       u[0] == 0,
       u'[0] == \[Minus]c /\[Lambda],
       u'' (0) == \[Minus]c *((1/(((\[Gamma]^2) - 
                4)*\[Lambda]^2))*(\[Minus](Subscript[\[Beta], 
                 0])^2  *(\[Gamma]^2) *(\[Sigma]^2) + 
             4 *(Subscript[\[Beta], 0])^2 * \[Sigma]^2 + 
             2* (\[Gamma]^2) *\[Lambda] \[Minus] 
             2 *(\[Gamma]^2) *Subscript[\[Mu], \[Infinity]] + 
             2 *(\[Gamma]^2) *Subscript[\[Mu], 0] \[Minus] 
             2 *\[Gamma]*x*Subscript[\[Mu], \[Infinity]] \[Minus] 
             8 *\[Lambda] + 4 *Subscript[\[Mu], \[Infinity]] \[Minus] 
             8 *Subscript[\[Mu], 0] + 
             4 *\[Gamma]*Subscript[\[Mu], \[Infinity]]* Subscript[p, 2]))} 
      , u[x], {x}]
```

'''

Re-pasting my initial text here as stackexchange wouldn't let me post this without adding more detail.
I am trying to solve the following set of ODEs for u(x) but I am stuck with this error. I am not sure why this is happening. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you :) (code is in the comments)

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please load Mathematica code (not an image) such that respondents can copy it to their notebooks. Thanks.

Comment: You have a syntax error:  u'' (0)

Comment: Thankyou for spotting that! Now when I run it, there is no error, however it takes a few minutes to compute and it doesn't give a solution. It just returns the DSolve Input, with the equations rearranged. Do you know why this is happening. Are there too many variables to compute?